Android Xamarin Widget
I'm trying to develop an Android app using Xamarin (Visual Studio) with C# language.
First, I'm following the steps on the webpage below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?pivots=windows
However, I'm having trouble with widget placement. No matter what I try, the widgets overlap each other as shown in the image.
If anyone knows the cause, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Checked the other websites.

Are you writing XML and everything overlaps? If yes mind sharing it here for me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You mentioned that widgets are overlapping each other. Most likely it's because of a layering issue.
Can you paste the layout xml you're using?
If you're using a RelativeLayout make sure that you layer widgets relative to each other.
For example:
Let's say you have 2 TextViews:
<RelativeLayout>

   <TextView android:text="Sample Text 1" android:id="@+id/sampleText1"/>

   <TextView android:text="Sample Text2" android:id="@+id/sampleText2"/>

</RelativeLayout>

If you want SampleText1 to be above SampleText2 you should do this:
     <RelativeLayout>
        
           <TextView android:text="Sample Text 1" android:id="@+id/sampleText1"/>
        
           <TextView android:text="Sample Text2" android:id="@+id/sampleText2"
android:layout_below="@id/sampleText1"/>
        
        </RelativeLayout>

And second, why are you using Xamarin?
Xamarin is officially out of support.
https://acagroup.be/en/blog/xamarin-support-discontinued-as-of-may-1-2024/#:~:text=However%2C%20Microsoft%20has%20decided%20to,will%20cease%20from%20that%20date.
If you're trying to develop natively then you should learn native.
https://developer.android.com/kotlin
Go to the source. There's always going to be work there.
